# Foreign Key constraints using dbForge Query Builder

Tags: php, mysql, dbforge

I am beginner for dbForge Query Builder,Can I set foreign key constrains using this query Builder easily,

Comment: Write proper title in questions like Foreign Key constraints using dbForge Query Builder

Answer (score 0):

As its description says - No.

http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/querybuilder/

It is a tool for building queries and data managing. For managing schemas you probably need to move to [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/ru/dbforge/mysql/studio/)