# How to use dbforge[of codeigniter] to add foreign key

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter and I am trying to convert following query into dbforge style query, how can I do it?

```
create table filter (
    filterid int primary key auto_increment,
    filtername varchar(50) not null,
    categoryid int not null,
    isactive tinyint not null,
    sequence int not null,
    foreign key(categoryid) references category(id));
```

Comment: Please refer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496216/foreign-key-constraints-using-dbforge-query-builder

Comment: The links provided in the answer of that question do not mention codeigniter, not even once! I am looking for an answer related to dbforge class in codeigniter.

Comment: I do not see any where for foreign key. But you can check for add_key
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/forge.html#add_key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$this->db->query();` instead.

This always works for me....

```
$sql="create table filter (
filterid int primary key auto_increment,
filtername varchar(50) not null,
categoryid int not null,
isactive tinyint not null,
sequence int not null,
foreign key(categoryid) references category(id))";

$this->db->query($sql);
```

Comment: Turns out, there is no such feature in codeigniter. `$this->db->query()` is indeed the only option.

Answer (score 11):

Here are 4 ways to do that. The first three work with create_table and the fourth one can be done when adding a field later.

```
$this->dbforge->add_field('id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY');

$this->dbforge->add_field('CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES table(id)');

$this->dbforge->add_field('INDEX (deleted)');

$this->dbforge->add_column('table',[
    'COLUMN id INT NULL AFTER field',
    'CONSTRAINT fk_id FOREIGN KEY(id) REFERENCES table(id)',
]);
```

Comment: what does table(id) mean is table representing table name ?

Comment: Yes, replace table with your table name, and replace id with your primary key name, if it is not id.